# C# 6, VS2015-3, .Net 4.6, System.Numerics.Vectors has no Vector<T>

Tags: c#, vector, .net-4.6, system.numerics

I am upgrading an application from Visual Studio 2013 Net 4.5.1 to Visual Studio 2015 C#6 Net 4.6, and I would like to make use of the `System.Numerics.Vectors Vector< T >`.  I have been using Vector4 already to get SIMD which works fine in my app, I would like to get Vector< T > support though and make full use of the larger AVX/AVX2 SIMD Registers.

The development system has Net 4.5, 4.51, 4.52, 4.6, 4.61 and 4.62 Multi-Target Packs and SDKs installed.
The project properties Target Framework is 4.6.  I also tried 4.61.
The project references include both `System.Numerics` (4.6.81.0) and `System.Numerics.Vectors` (4.6.81.0).

But all that I get in the `System.Numerics` namespace is the BigInteger, Complex, Matrix3x2/4x4, Plane, Quaternion, Vector2/3/4.
I do not get Vector< T >.

At this late stage (2019) am I still supposed to install the old NuGet Preview packages to still get the Vector< T >?  Is Vector< T > not by now a part of the current .Net 4.6 and 4.61 public releases?
And if I do have to use the old NuGet, is the NuGet package just the relevant information for VS and the JIT, or does that mean that I have to distribute another DLL even though `System.Numerics.Vectors` is already on the system...

I must be stupid...

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.vector-1?view=netstandard-2.1#applies-to .NET 4.6 doesn't implement .NET Standard 2.1 Preview, why do you expect this to apply to .NET 4.6?

Comment: @ta.speot.is - I expected it because Microsoft says that Net 4.6 includes Vector< T >, see this page: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-framework-4-6/ . ... And because Microsoft also said that Vector< T > is part of System.Numerics.Vectors which IS on my system in the References, see this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/numerics .  That is why I commented that I must be stupid or something because what MS is saying apparently isn't true.  :)

Comment: `Numerics.Vector<T>` is never part of the .NET Framework. [Not even 4.8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics?view=netframework-4.8). It is part of .NET Core [since 1.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics?view=netcore-1.0). PS: There's a dropdown on the top left of the page to select your API level.

Comment: Ok, thanks everyone.

Comment: FYI, I have the NuGet installed and everything is fine.

Answer (score 1):

`Vector<T>` is only in the *.Net 2.1 standard preview*, no it's not part of *.Net Framework*.

> **Applies to**
>
> - *.NET Core*: 3.0 Preview 3 2.2 2.1 2.0 1.1 1.0
> - *.NET Standard*: 2.1 Preview
> - *UWP*: 10.0
> - *Xamarin.Android*: 7.1
> - *Xamarin.iOS*: 10.8
> - *Xamarin.Mac*: 3.0

Yes you will have to include the *nuget*, which will have its own *Assembly*

> is the NuGet package just the relevant information for VS and the JIT

As far as I know there is no compiler magic and `Vector<T>`, it's just a vanilla struct, so what you are including are the definitions of this structure, this is all.